# Use pandas groupby exctract data and transposition

Tags: python, pandas

The data is simplified as follow:

```
mon  site   year  data1 data2
1   57598  2001  58    1383 
2   57598  2001  75    549 
1   57598  2002  118   1337 
2   57598  2002  162   2213 

1   50136  2000  -282   134 
2   50136  2000  -242   0 
1   50136  2001  -126   102 

1   50844  2000  152   411 
2   50844  2000  70    117 
1   50844  2002  -74    44 
2   50844  2002  -173   83
```

I want to extract the data1 and data2 and change to following form:
this is `data1`:

```
      2000   2000    2001 2001 2002 2002
        1      2      1      2    1   2
50136   -282  -242  -126    NA   NA   NA
50844   152   70    NA      NA  -74  -173
57598   58    75    NA      NA   118  162
```

and `data2` will be saved as new file with the same form to `data1`. 
I want to use `pandas.groupby` to operate, but the code as follow is error:

```
df['data1'].groupby(df['year'],df['mon'],df['site'])
```

Is easy to go by using `groupby`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think first is best try [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
df1 = df.set_index(['year','mon','site'])['data1'].unstack(level=[0,1]).sort_index(axis=1)
print (df1)
year    2000          2001         2002       
mon        1      2      1     2      1      2
site                                          
50136 -282.0 -242.0 -126.0   NaN    NaN    NaN
50844  152.0   70.0    NaN   NaN  -74.0 -173.0
57598    NaN    NaN   58.0  75.0  118.0  162.0
```

but if get:

> ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

use another solution with `groupby` or `pivot_table`:

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby(['year','mon','site'])['data1'].mean().unstack(level=[0,1])
print (df1)
year    2000          2001         2002       
mon        1      2      1     2      1      2
site                                          
50136 -282.0 -242.0 -126.0   NaN    NaN    NaN
50844  152.0   70.0    NaN   NaN  -74.0 -173.0
57598    NaN    NaN   58.0  75.0  118.0  162.0
```

Another possible solution with [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) with default `aggfunc` which is `np.mean`, but can be changed to another functions like `aggfunc='sum'`, ...:

```
print (df.pivot_table(index='site', columns=['year','mon'], values='data1', aggfunc=np.mean))
year    2000          2001         2002       
mon        1      2      1     2      1      2
site                                          
50136 -282.0 -242.0 -126.0   NaN    NaN    NaN
50844  152.0   70.0    NaN   NaN  -74.0 -173.0
57598    NaN    NaN   58.0  75.0  118.0  162.0
```

Last use [`DataFrame.to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) for write file to `csv`.

```
df1.to_csv('file_out.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the df in the shape in which you need it:

```
result = df.groupby(['site','mon','year'])['data1'].mean().unstack().unstack()
Out[310]: 
year    2000          2001         2002       
mon        1      2      1     2      1      2
site                                          
50136 -282.0 -242.0 -126.0   NaN    NaN    NaN
50844  152.0   70.0    NaN   NaN  -74.0 -173.0
57598    NaN    NaN   58.0  75.0  118.0  162.0
```

To save it to csv:

```
df.groupby(['site','mon','year'])['data1'].mean().unstack().unstack().to_csv('data1.csv')
df.groupby(['site','mon','year'])['data2'].mean().unstack().unstack().to_csv('data2.csv')
```